# How to make pc and mobile layout for a Rails application?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, mobile, layout

I have follow this tutorial to do:

> http://railscasts.com/episodes/199-mobile-devices?view=asciicast

Now I have `app/views/layouts/pc.html.erb` and `app/views/layouts/mobile.html.erb`.

I tried to add these code to application_controller.rb:

```
private

def mobile_device?
  if session[:mobile_param]
    session[:mobile_param] == "1"
  else
    request.user_agent =~ /Mobile/
  end
end

def prepare_for_mobile
  session[:mobile_param] = params[:mobile] if params[:mobile]
  request.format = :mobile if mobile_device?
end

protected

def layout_by_device
  if mobile_device?
    render layout: "mobile"
  else
    render layout: "pc"
  end
end
```

And in my products_controller.rb:

```
before_action :layout_by_device

def show
  respond_to do |format|
    format.html
    format.mobile
  end
end
```

But I can only see my mobile layout's content, I can't see product page's content with `:yield`.

If I remove `before_action :layout_by_device` and use `render layout: 'mobile'` in my products_controller.rb, I can see the product page's content but can't see the mobile layout's.

Maybe this is about Rails' `respond_to` and `render`. How to do?

Comment: Why don't you using `twitter-bootstrap`?

Comment: @Emu Because we are using different design between pc and mobile. We have our self's design and we are not using twitter-bootstrap.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not trying to discourage you from following the tutorial, but if your goal is to adjust your app to small screens and their limitations, the approach of maintaining separate layouts/views is rather outdated. Your time would be better spent on learning responsive webdesign, which is the concept of letting page elements grow/shrink with the available screen size.

Comment: Thank you very much. But now we are design two different layout for pc and mobile. Even the feature are different. So we should try to find a way to deal both pc and mobile device.

Comment: Ok, in that case, you might want to take a look at Action Pack Variants which does exactly what you had in mind and was introduced recently with Rails 4.1: [See here](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/4_1_release_notes.html#action-pack-variants)

In contrast to the Railscasts guide, this is a more recent and the recommended approach to achieve your goal. If possible, it's always preferable to stick with the best practices.

Comment: Yes. I have found it. And it works well for me. Thank you very much:)

Answer (score 1):

I found the right solution:

> http://guides.rubyonrails.org/4_1_release_notes.html

**2.3 Action Pack Variants** is what I wanted.

```
request.variant
```